# how to protect Wordpress RSS Feed from "Feed Fetcher"

Tags: plugins, rss

how to protect Wordpress RSS Feed from "Feed Fetcher" ?
there is a plugin "disable Feed for wordpress but in want rss feed for seo. wat can i do to protect RSS FEED from copying without IP BANNING in HTACCESS cause there is lots of FEED FETCHER website!

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look in your logs to find what User-Agent string Feed Fetcher is using, and then you can block it using that, e.g.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Firefox/70.0" blockua
Deny from env=blockua
```

By adding the above to my `.htaccess` file, I was able to block the Firefox (version 70.0) but Chrome still had access.

Obviously, you need to change the string "Firefox/70.0" to whatever the Feed Fetcher user-agent string is, and most likely you don't want the entire string, but just a part that look unique to that piece of software and won't accidentally block something else.